# Windows - How to explore the devices by connection. Like Windows "Device Manager"

Tags: c#, wmi, device-manager

**The idea is to start from the VID and PID of USB hub and then explore its contents.**

Given a USB hub how do we explore the connected devices?

I need to programmatically explore the attacked devices to a USB hub,
some of these devices can be "USB Composite Device".

I'd like to do as "Device Manager":

[image: Device Manager]

I tried run some queries with WMI, but I did not get any result.

*PS: My reference  language is C#.*

Comment: Hi there, in order to best help you with your question, please provide the C# source code you're written so far in order for us to see what might be wrong with the code.

Comment: Check this one, I posted some pointers as an answer there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31677687/wmi-query-parent-children-of-pnp-entity/76276557#76276557 Also, good information can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371578/find-usb-drive-letter-from-vid-pid-needed-for-xp-and-higher

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementobjectsearcher.aspx

Watch more in depth using System.Management