# Find Windows Drive Letter of a removable disk from USB VID/PID

Tags: c#, .net

This question has been asked before, and there is one answer that supposedly works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371578/find-usb-drive-letter-from-vid-pid-needed-for-xp-and-higher). But I've tried it out and it does not work for me.

The issue is that the PNPDeviceID returned by the Query on Win32_DiskDrive and that returned by the "Device" class are different. For example in my case the Query returns something like - PNPDeviceID: **USBSTOR\DISK&VEN_ABCD&PROD_1234&REV_0001\8&2C3C9390&0** while the Device class returns the actual VID/PID combination --> **USB\VID_4568&PID_QWER&MI_00\7&15b8d7f0&3&0000**.

So the SELECT query on Win32_DiskDrive always fails.

Main Code:

```
    var usbDevices = GetUSBDevices();

    //Enumerate the USB devices to see if any have specific VID/PID
    foreach (var usbDevice in usbDevices)
    {
        if (usbDevice.DeviceID.Contains("ABCD") && usbDevice.DeviceID.Contains("1234"))
        {
            foreach (string name in usbDevice.GetDiskNames())
            {
                //Open dialog to show file names
                Debug.WriteLine(name);
            }
        }                   
    }
```

USBDeviceInfo Class

```
class USBDeviceInfo
{
    public USBDeviceInfo(string deviceID, string pnpDeviceID, string description)
    {
        this.DeviceID = deviceID;
        this.PnpDeviceID = pnpDeviceID;
        this.Description = description;
    }

    public string DeviceID { get; private set; }
    public string PnpDeviceID { get; private set; }
    public string Description { get; private set; }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetDiskNames()
    {
        using (Device device = Device.Get(PnpDeviceID))
        {
            // get children devices
            foreach (string childDeviceId in device.ChildrenPnpDeviceIds)
            {
                // get the drive object that correspond to this id (escape the id)
                Debug.WriteLine(childDeviceId.Replace(@"\", @"\\") );
                foreach (ManagementObject drive in new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT DeviceID FROM Win32_DiskDrive WHERE PNPDeviceID='" + childDeviceId.Replace(@"\", @"\\") + "'").Get())
                {

                    foreach (PropertyData usb in drive.Properties){
                        if (usb.Value != null && usb.Value.ToString() != "")
                        {
                            Debug.Write(usb.Name + "=");
                            Debug.Write(usb.Value + "\r\n");
                        }
                    }

                    // associate physical disks with partitions
                    foreach (ManagementObject partition in new ManagementObjectSearcher("ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID='" + drive["DeviceID"] + "'} WHERE AssocClass=Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition").Get())
                    {
                        // associate partitions with logical disks (drive letter volumes)
                        foreach (ManagementObject disk in new ManagementObjectSearcher("ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID='" + partition["DeviceID"] + "'} WHERE AssocClass=Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition").Get())
                        {
                            yield return (string)disk["DeviceID"];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

As a side note, I am able to get the Query using "Model" property pass and then find the drive letter, as explained [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/63878/Enumerate-and-Auto-Detect-USB-Drives). But I'm looking for a solution that can tie VID/PID to the drive letter.

Comment: I used Michaela's answer in my library: https://github.com/Jinjinov/Usb.Events

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem and after a hard week of work I finally got the solution.
I also get two links for one device (the link with the vid and pid and a link, which contains "USBSTOR...."). I think it's not the best way to solve the problem, but (until now) it works.

I used two functions:

The first one is to find a USBHub with a specific VID and PID and also find the related second link ("USBSTOR...."). This link is important, because it forms the connection to the drive letter.
A list named "USBobjects" contains a number of related links (USBHub, USBSTOR,....), which refer to all attached devices. I found out, that the USBSTOR link appears right after the link, which contains the VID and PID.
I stored the "USBStOR..." link as a string and used it for the second function to find the related PNPEntity of the DiskDrive. This leads to the correct DiskPartition and furthermore to the LogicalDisk = drive letter.

Hopefully it's not to late and both functions will help u!

FIRST FUNCTION:

```
    public void FindPath()
    {
        foreach (ManagementObject entity in new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_USBHub Where DeviceID Like '%VID_XXXX&PID_XXXX%'").Get())
        {
            Entity = entity["DeviceID"].ToString();

            foreach (ManagementObject controller in entity.GetRelated("Win32_USBController"))
            {
                foreach (ManagementObject obj in new ManagementObjectSearcher("ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_USBController.DeviceID='" + controller["PNPDeviceID"].ToString() + "'}").Get())
                {
                    if(obj.ToString().Contains("DeviceID"))
                        USBobjects.Add(obj["DeviceID"].ToString());

                }
            }

        }

        int VidPidposition = USBobjects.IndexOf(Entity);
        for (int i = VidPidposition; i <= USBobjects.Count; i++ )
        {
            if (USBobjects[i].Contains("USBSTOR"))
            {
                Secondentity = USBobjects[i];
                break;
            }

        }
    }
```

>

SECOND FUNCTION:

```
    public void GetDriveLetter()
    {
        foreach (ManagementObject drive in new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_DiskDrive").Get())
            {
                if (drive["PNPDeviceID"].ToString() == Secondentity)
                {
                    foreach (ManagementObject o in drive.GetRelated("Win32_DiskPartition"))
                    {
                        foreach (ManagementObject i in o.GetRelated("Win32_LogicalDisk"))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Disk: " + i["Name"].ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

>

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! It really works :) I'll change my code to use this method.

Answer (score 2):

many thanks to @Michaela for his very helpful answer, but I think this code is shorter

```
public void FindPath()
{
   ManagementObjectSearcher entity = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive");
   foreach (ManagementObject obj in entity.Get())
   {
      if (obj["PNPDeviceID"].ToString().Contains("USBSTOR"))
      {
         if (!USBobjects.Contains(obj["PNPDeviceID"].ToString()))
            USBobjects.Add(obj["PNPDeviceID"].ToString());
      }
   }
}
```

I have another problem with `GetDriveLetter()` method, sometimes it takes too long to compile `foreach` line. can somebody tell me the reason?

Comment: This code is shorter, but OP specifically asked to use VID/PID to get the drive letter.

Answer (score -1):

```
 DriveInfo[] ListDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

            foreach (DriveInfo Drive in ListDrives)
            {
                if (Drive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(Drive.Name);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {    
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }                     
                }
            }
```

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for. I want to be able to know the drive letter from the VID/PID combination, not blindly search all the removable drives. thanks for answering anyway.