# How to get drive letter of usb drive from vendor/product id?

Tags: c#, usb

I only know the Vendor and Product ID of a usb drive but I need to be able to get all drive letters associated to this device.

System.IO.DriveInfo doesn't give any IDs with which I can find the vid/pid.

LibUsb wrappers have the opposite problem -- tons of id information but nothing that I can connect to a mount point.

Comment: Are you able to get the vendor and product id from the USB drive if it is plugged into the computer?

Comment: The drive letter assigned to the device depends on how many and type of other drives are already plugged into the system, and what drive letters are already assigned to them.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but I'd like to be able to access the filesystem of a particular usb device when I can't be guaranteed what the drive letter or volume label is.

Comment: Scan all available drives and find something on the USB drive that is unique to that particular drive.

Answer (score 0):

There was a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20405583/1911064) several years ago.

I adapted the code of the answer:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //  example call
    string device = FindPath("VID_0781&PID_5583");

    GetDriveLetter(device); 
}

static public string FindPath(string pattern)
{
    var USBobjects = new List<string>();
    string Entity = "*none*";

    foreach (ManagementObject entity in new ManagementObjectSearcher(
             $"select * from Win32_USBHub Where DeviceID Like '%{pattern}%'").Get())
    {
        Entity = entity["DeviceID"].ToString();

        foreach (ManagementObject controller in entity.GetRelated("Win32_USBController"))
        {
            foreach (ManagementObject obj in new ManagementObjectSearcher(
                     "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_USBController.DeviceID='" 
                     + controller["PNPDeviceID"].ToString() + "'}").Get())
            {
                if (obj.ToString().Contains("DeviceID"))
                    USBobjects.Add(obj["DeviceID"].ToString());

            }
        }
    }

    int VidPidposition = USBobjects.IndexOf(Entity);
    for (int i = VidPidposition; i <= USBobjects.Count; i++)
    {
        if (USBobjects[i].Contains("USBSTOR"))
        {
            return USBobjects[i];
        }
    }

    return "*none*";
}

public static void GetDriveLetter(string device)
{
    int driveCount = 0;

    foreach (ManagementObject drive in new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_DiskDrive").Get())
    {
        if (drive["PNPDeviceID"].ToString() == device)
        {
            foreach (ManagementObject o in drive.GetRelated("Win32_DiskPartition"))
            {
                foreach (ManagementObject i in o.GetRelated("Win32_LogicalDisk"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Disk: " + i["Name"].ToString());
                    driveCount++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (driveCount == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No drive identified!");
    }
}
```

Some error handling and optimization would make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works for me, giving you all drives matching your vendor and product ids. Not all the code was written by me.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <setupapi.h>
#include <cfgmgr32.h>
#include <winioctl.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 256
#define MAX_DRIVES 26

// Finds the device interface for the CDROM drive with the given interface number.
DEVINST GetDrivesDevInstByDeviceNumber(long DeviceNumber)
{
   const GUID *guid = &GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DISK;

   // Get device interface info set handle
   // for all devices attached to system
   HDEVINFO hDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(guid, NULL, NULL, DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE);
   if (hDevInfo == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
      return 0;

   // Retrieve a context structure for a device interface of a device information set.
   BYTE buf[1024];
   PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA pspdidd = (PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA)buf;
   SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA spdid;
   SP_DEVINFO_DATA spdd;
   DWORD dwSize;

   spdid.cbSize = sizeof(spdid);

   // Iterate through all the interfaces and try to match one based on
   // the device number.
   for (DWORD i = 0; SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(hDevInfo, NULL, guid, i, &spdid); i++)
   {
      // Get the device path.
      dwSize = 0;
      SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(hDevInfo, &spdid, NULL, 0, &dwSize, NULL);
      if (dwSize == 0 || dwSize > sizeof(buf))
         continue;

      pspdidd->cbSize = sizeof(*pspdidd);
      ZeroMemory((PVOID)&spdd, sizeof(spdd));
      spdd.cbSize = sizeof(spdd);
      if (!SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(hDevInfo, &spdid, pspdidd,
                                           dwSize, &dwSize, &spdd))
         continue;

      // Open the device.
      HANDLE hDrive = CreateFile(pspdidd->DevicePath, 0,
                                 FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                                 NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
      if (hDrive == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
         continue;

      // Get the device number.
      STORAGE_DEVICE_NUMBER sdn;
      dwSize = 0;
      if (DeviceIoControl(hDrive,
                          IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER,
                          NULL, 0, &sdn, sizeof(sdn),
                          &dwSize, NULL))
      {
         // Does it match?
         if (DeviceNumber == (long)sdn.DeviceNumber)
         {
            CloseHandle(hDrive);
            SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(hDevInfo);
            return spdd.DevInst;
         }
      }
      CloseHandle(hDrive);
   }

   SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(hDevInfo);
   return 0;
}

// Returns true if the given device instance belongs to the USB device with the given VID and PID.
boolean matchDevInstToUsbDevice(DEVINST device, DWORD vid, DWORD pid)
{
   // This is the string we will be searching for in the device harware IDs.
   TCHAR hwid[64];
   sprintf(hwid, "VID_%04X&PID_%04X", vid, pid);

   // Get a list of hardware IDs for all USB devices.
   ULONG ulLen;
   CM_Get_Device_ID_List_Size(&ulLen, NULL, CM_GETIDLIST_FILTER_NONE);
   TCHAR *pszBuffer = malloc(sizeof(TCHAR) * ulLen);
   CM_Get_Device_ID_List(NULL, pszBuffer, ulLen, CM_GETIDLIST_FILTER_NONE);

   // Iterate through the list looking for our ID.
   for (LPTSTR pszDeviceID = pszBuffer; *pszDeviceID; pszDeviceID += _tcslen(pszDeviceID) + 1)
   {
      // Some versions of Windows have the string in upper case and other versions have it
      // in lower case so just make it all upper.
      for (int i = 0; pszDeviceID[i]; i++)
         pszDeviceID[i] = toupper(pszDeviceID[i]);

      if (_tcsstr(pszDeviceID, hwid))
      {
         // Found the device, now we want the grandchild device, which is the "generic volume"
         DEVINST MSDInst = 0;
         if (CR_SUCCESS == CM_Locate_DevNode(&MSDInst, pszDeviceID, CM_LOCATE_DEVNODE_NORMAL))
         {
            DEVINST DiskDriveInst = 0;
            if (CR_SUCCESS == CM_Get_Child(&DiskDriveInst, MSDInst, 0))
            {
               // Now compare the grandchild node against the given device instance.
               if (device == DiskDriveInst)
                  return TRUE;
            }
         }
      }
   }

   return FALSE;
}

int scan_drives(DWORD vid, DWORD pid)
{
   TCHAR caDrive[4] = TEXT("A:\\");
   TCHAR volume[BUFFER_SIZE];
   TCHAR volume_path_name[BUFFER_SIZE];
   DWORD dwDriveMask;

   int count = 0;

   // Get all drives in the system.
   dwDriveMask = GetLogicalDrives();

   if (dwDriveMask == 0)
   {
      printf("Error - GetLogicalDrives failed\n");
      return -1;
   }

   // Loop for all drives.
   for (int nLoopIndex = 0; nLoopIndex < MAX_DRIVES; nLoopIndex++, dwDriveMask >>= 1)
   {
      // If a drive is present,
      if (dwDriveMask & 1)
      {
         caDrive[0] = TEXT('A') + nLoopIndex;

         // If a drive is removable.
         if (GetDriveType(caDrive) == DRIVE_REMOVABLE)
         {
            //Get its volume info.
            if (GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPoint(caDrive, volume, BUFFER_SIZE))
            {
               DWORD lpcchReturnLength;

               GetVolumePathNamesForVolumeName(volume, volume_path_name, BUFFER_SIZE, &lpcchReturnLength);

               char szVolumeAccessPath[] = "\\\\.\\X:";
               szVolumeAccessPath[4] = caDrive[0];

               long DeviceNumber = -1;

               HANDLE hVolume = CreateFile(szVolumeAccessPath, 0, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);

               if (hVolume == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
               {
                  return 1;
               }

               STORAGE_DEVICE_NUMBER sdn;
               DWORD dwBytesReturned = 0;

               long res = DeviceIoControl(hVolume, IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER, NULL, 0, &sdn, sizeof(sdn), &dwBytesReturned, NULL);

               if (res)
               {
                  DeviceNumber = sdn.DeviceNumber;
               }

               CloseHandle(hVolume);

               if (DeviceNumber != -1)
               {
                  DEVINST DevInst = GetDrivesDevInstByDeviceNumber(DeviceNumber);

                  boolean match = matchDevInstToUsbDevice(DevInst, vid, pid);

                  if (match)
                  {
                     printf("%s\t0x%04x\t0x%04x\n", volume_path_name, vid, pid);
                  }
               }

               count++;
            }
         }
      }
   }

   return count;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

   if (argc > 1)
   {

      if (argc % 2 == 0)
      {
         return -1;
      }

      for (int i = 1; i < argc - 1; i += 2)
      {
         int vid, pid;

         sscanf(argv[i], "%x", &vid);
         sscanf(argv[i + 1], "%x", &pid);

         scan_drives(vid, pid);
      }
   }

   return 0;
}
```