# How to use WMI to get BOTH the numerical vid/pid and the drive letter from an usb drive

Tags: c#, usb, wmi, drive

I am trying to show the vid/pid and the drive letter of a usb drive when I connect it to my computer. I'm actually able to do both, but not at the same time.

1: I can use `Win32_DiskDrive` to get to `Win32_LogicalDisk` and extract the drive letter. But the deviceId has a non-numerical pid/vid which I can't use.

2: I can use `Win32_USBHub` or `Win32_PnPEntity` to extract the vid/pid, but I can't find a link between them and the drive letter.

```
public void CheckForUsbDevice()
        {
            string text =
                "SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent " +
                "WITHIN 2 "
              + "WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_PnPEntity'";


            ManagementEventWatcher watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher();
            WqlEventQuery query = new WqlEventQuery(text);

            watcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(watcher_EventArrived);

            watcher.Query = query;
            watcher.Start();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static readonly Guid GUID_DEVCLASS_USB = new Guid("{36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000}");

        static void watcher_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
        {
            ManagementBaseObject instance = (ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent["TargetInstance"];
            if ((new Guid((string)instance["ClassGuid"]) == GUID_DEVCLASS_USB) && ((string)instance.Properties["Name"].Value == "USB Mass Storage Device"))
            {
                // we're only interested by USB devices, dump all props
                foreach (var property in instance.Properties)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(property.Name + " = " + property.Value);
                }
            }
        }
```

This has the output:

```
Availability =
Caption = USB Mass Storage Device
ClassGuid = {36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000}
CompatibleID = System.String[]
ConfigManagerErrorCode = 0
ConfigManagerUserConfig = False
CreationClassName = Win32_PnPEntity
Description = USB Mass Storage Device
DeviceID = USB\VID_0911&PID_1F40&MI_00\6&27CAD51B&0&0000
ErrorCleared =
ErrorDescription =
HardwareID = System.String[]
InstallDate =
LastErrorCode =
Manufacturer = Compatible USB storage device
Name = USB Mass Storage Device
PNPClass = USB
PNPDeviceID = USB\VID_0911&PID_1F40&MI_00\6&27CAD51B&0&0000
PowerManagementCapabilities =
PowerManagementSupported =
Present = True
Service = USBSTOR
Status = OK
StatusInfo =
SystemCreationClassName = Win32_ComputerSystem
SystemName = WINDEV1905EVAL
```

I need a link between WMI classed containing the numerical pid/vid and the drive letter or a different way how that can be achieved.

I think it might be possible to use `DeviceIoControl`, but I have no idea where to start there.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You can see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20143264/find-windows-drive-letter-of-a-removable-disk-from-usb-vid-pid) (I tested about the same method and it works for me (USB stick on Windows 10)

Comment: That solution works if I only have one usb device connected, but stops working with two or more. It lists both drive letters for each of the devices. Thanks for pointing me to that tho!

Comment: Or you can change the filter on the event
When I plug my USB stick, I receive 4 events : GUID_DEVCLASS_USB, GUID_DEVCLASS_VOLUME, GUID_DEVCLASS_WPD, GUID_DEVCLASS_DISKDRIVE
And with GUID_DEVCLASS_DISKDRIVE, I get the right drive letter from the PNPDeviceID (USBSTOR\DISK&VEN_CORSAIR&PROD_FLASH_VOYAGER&REV_1.00\00080221D6417DA200BB&0)