# WMI Query Parent/Children of PNP_entity

Tags: c#, usb, wmi

I am currently developing a program to check if a USB device has been detected on a specific USB hub in C#. I know the PID and VID of both the hub and the slave device connected to the hub.
I am doing this using a ManagementObjectSearcher Query to get the devices:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher USBSearchQuery = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE DeviceID LIKE \"%VID_17EF&PID_6019%\"");
ManagementObjectCollection DeviceCollection = USBSearchQuery.Get();
```

This works quite fine. The ManagementObjectCollection DeviceCollection contains 2 elements. One HID device and one USB device. When I check with the device manager, I see the elements and can access the property Parent, but it seems to be impossible to get either the parent or the children of an object through a WMI query.

I could do this either through the children of the hub or the parent of the device. Do any of you have an idea how to do this?

Comment: I know this is a long time ago but did you ever find the solution to this ? I'm having the exact same use case !

Answer (score 0):

```
ManagementObjectCollection DeviceCollection = USBSearchQuery .Get();
foreach (ManagementObject mo in DeviceCollection )
    {
      //get all properties 
      //ex: mo.Properties["Description"].Value represents the friendly name of the device
      //mo.Properties["PNPClass"].Value represents the parent class of the device
    }
```

Comment: The question was about the parent device (by connection), not the parent class.

Answer (score 0):

The solution here is to use WinApi:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/determining-the-parent-of-a-device

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/devpkey-device-parent

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupdigetdevicepropertyw

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfgmgr32/nf-cfgmgr32-cm_get_devnode_propertyw

I haven't implemented this solution yet, so this info is as-is and no warranties :)

Also, more info here: [Find USB drive letter from VID/PID (Needed for XP and higher)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371578/find-usb-drive-letter-from-vid-pid-needed-for-xp-and-higher)